# Elasticsearch with both wildcard and quotes

Tags: elasticsearch

In database I have the following entries:

```
fotball 9
fotball
fotb
```

What I need is to match all above entries if I write the term:

```
fot
```

or the term:

```
otb
```

Only match "fotball 9" and "fotball" if the term is:

```
fotball
```

But also only match "fotball 9" if the term is:

```
fotball 9
```

My query looks like this:

```
"query": { 
    "bool": { 
        "must": [
            {"query_string": {"query": '*'+mystring+'*'}}
        ]
    }
}
```

This works except the term:

```
fotball 9
```

Which returns both "fotball" and "fotball 9"

I have tried having both quotes and asterisk but they don't seem to work well togheter.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Modify `query_string` query with `default_operator` to `AND`.

Comment: Thank you. But I dont really understand how to rewrite the whole query. Could you write it according to the current one? I mean of course only the inner part: {"query_string": {"query": '*'+mystring+'*'}}

Comment: Check this: `"query": { 
    "bool": { 
        "must": [
            {"query_string": {"query": '*'+mystring+'*',
      "default_operator": "AND"}}
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: That query ^ will also match a document that has `fotball bla 9` ;-) @avr and @oderfla.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I don't know if this app requires it. But in that case: how would you solve it? I mean, if you don't want to match "fotball bla 9" when searching for "football 9".